# UISearchBar responding to TouchesBegan instead of Delegate Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` that is responding to `TouchesBegan` instead of its **Delegate Methods**.. i have set its delegate in code as

```
self.searchbar.delegate = self;
```

as well as hooked it up in `IB`

I have implemented the following delegate methods as well

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar { }
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar { }
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar { }
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar { }
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text { }
```

the touchesBegan method is

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: delegate methods are not called.. instead `TouchesBegan` are called.. i need too delegate methods to be called for `UISearchBar`.

Comment: touchesBegan should get called only when you touch the search bar because it super class is UIResponder, where touchesBegan method is defined. i think you should check ins storyboard if outlets are hooked up correctly.

Comment: @pawan ok em checking again..

Comment: Did you do `<UISearchBarDelegate>` in you header?

Comment: @AhmedZ its better if you can post you code to any git repository site & send a link here. so we can check whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem.. The only work around i was able to get was change the `[self.taber tleView setUserInteraction:NO]`; to `self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;`.. This wasn't allowing the SearchBar to call its delegate methods.. after changing the above line, the `UISearchbar` was finally able to call its delegate methods on its touch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point your custom delegate to your object:

Replace `self.searchbar.delegate = self;` to `self.searchbar.yourCustomDelegate = self;`